# groupby two columns take highest sum (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

Looking to see which client has the highest price sum for the month of February. 2/1/2022

**Data**

```
client  box Price   date
charles AA  5,000   2/1/2022
charles AA  5,050   2/1/2022
charles AA  5,075   2/1/2022
cara    BB  25,116  2/1/2022
cara    BB  5,154   2/1/2022
lu      CC  0       2/1/2022
max     DD  10,000  3/1/2022
```

**Desired**

```
   client   box Price   date
   cara     BB  30,270  2/1/2022
```

**Doing**

```
df.groupby(['client','date']) \
.agg({'Price':'sum'}).reset_index() \
```

Any suggestion is helpful.

Comment: will box ever be different for the same client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) will return the index of the maximum value—which you can then use to look up the row you want. Be aware that in the case that two customers are tied for the highest price, it will return only the first occurence.

Example:

```py
(
    df
    # Fist filter to only Februrary
    .loc[lambda df_: df_["date"].dt.month == 2]
    .groupby(["client", "box"])["Price"]
    .sum()
    .reset_index()
    # Then select where price is max
    .loc[lambda df_: df_["Price"].idxmax()]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"client": ["charles", "charles", "charles", "cara", "cara", "lu", "max"],
                    "box": ["AA", "AA", "AA", "BB", "BB", "CC", "DD"],
                    "price": [5000, 5050, 5075, 25116, 5154, 0, 10000],
                    "date": ["2/1/2022", "2/1/2022", "2/1/2022", "2/1/2022", "2/1/2022", "2/1/2022", "3/1/2022"]})
# print(df)

print(df.groupby(by= ["client", "box", "date"]).price.aggregate('sum'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the OP's desired output, here is a suggestion:

```
gdf = df.groupby(['client','box','date']).agg({'Price':'sum'}).reset_index()
gdf.loc[gdf.Price.idxmax()]
```

Answer (score 1):

If box is always the same per client.

```
df = df.groupby(["client", "date"]).agg({"box": "first", "Price": "sum"})
df = df[df["Price"].eq(df["Price"].max())].reset_index()
```

If box could be different per client.

```
df = df.groupby(["client", "date", "box"]).agg({"Price": "sum"})
df = df[df["Price"].eq(df["Price"].max())].reset_index()
```